# why the currency data(such as USD/JPY) is different from different source

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, money-transfer, financing

I am a new guy to finance.
I found that the currency rates for USD/JPY or CNY/JPY have slightly different from different source.

For example: USD/JPY  2017/07/10

(1)  114.08: https://www.oanda.com/fx-for-business/historical-rates?view=graph&base=USD&quote=JPY&duration=90

(2). 114.15 by the forex_python:

```
>>> end_date = datetime.datetime(2017,7,10)
>>> c.get_rate('USD', 'JPY', end_date)
114.15
>>>
```

(3) 114.04 from: https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-jpy-historical-data

Could you tell me why cause these difference, which one is right for me .
Thanks!

Comment: use  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.forexlive this.

Comment: thanks! I just want the data that can be downloaded as csv file or other format like dataframe that I can be used for my application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A day is a long time and the rate is not the same all day. Some sources will report a close price that averages the bid and ask. Some sources will report a volume-weighted average. Some will report the last transaction price. Some will report a time-weighted average. Some will average the highest and lowest prices for the interval. Different marketplaces will also have slightly different prices because different traders are present at each marketplace. Usually, the documentation will explain what method they use and you can choose the source whose method makes the most sense for your application.

Comment: thanks for your kind answer, I want to get the close price of currency like stock price. Could you recommend me some sites or python API for getting such kind of currency,Please!

Comment: @tktktk0711 you didn't read the answer thoroughly enough.  In a nutshell: There is no consistent close price in FX.

Comment: thanks, I got it. I am sorry for this, I am a new guy to finance. Could you recommend some sites or API for me.

Comment: @tktktk0711 You've got three that you found yourself. In the light of David's excellent answer, what makes you think you need another one?